# Ready Find my iphone status

Tags: ios

We are developing an iPhone application for which i need to read iPhone Settings value (precisely the status of 'Settings->icloud-find my iphone'). Is there any  way to ***find out the status(enabled/disabled) of "Find my iphone"***? Any tips and tricks are most welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide which language that you are using and what are all the steps that you have tried. That will help to give the proper solution for you.

Comment: its not possible so for , you can get icloud logged in status but not find my iphone app logged in status